# log-convexity of Mollified function?

Tags: convexity, smoothing-theory

Let $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}_+$ be a [log-convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function) function. Suppose that $f_{\epsilon}$ is the smoothed version of $f$:

$$f_{\epsilon}(x)=\int \varphi_{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y)dy,$$

where $\varphi$ is a [Mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier). I would appreciate any pointers on relevant literature (or a hint) referring to conditions on $\varphi$ such that $f_{\epsilon}$ is log-convex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you assume $\phi_\epsilon\ge0$. Because $f_\epsilon$ belongs to the convex cone spanned by the shifted functions $f(\cdot-h)$. Since every $f(\cdot-h)$ is logarithmically convex and the set of logarithmically convex functions is itself a convex cone, you are done.

Comment: Thanks. I would also like to know what happens if $f$ depends on other variables,e.g. a parametric function, and is log-convex with respect to those variables (the parameters) that are not being Mollified.

Comment: Very nice answer for the question!